# Destroying timeout on controller leave in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a function like this, in an AngularJS controller

```
$timeout($scope.loadPosts, 5000); // pull every 5 seconds
```

When I navigate away from the controller (to another view), how can I stop the timeout and eventually destroy the controller so it is not running anymore?

Comment: The controller is destroyed anyway on navigating away.

Comment: But the timeout function did not stop from running

Comment: `$timeout` is just a wrapper for `setTimeout` which is handled internally. The number you get returned from `setTimeout` is actually not a reference but just the internal number you can use to then destroy the timer.

Comment: $timeout is only executed once. $interval is repeated.

Comment: @subZero is right here -- your $timeout will still get called even after the $scope it's contained in is destroyed. Probably won't bite you on short $timeout buts on long ones it can cause some strange, buggy behavior.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to solve it by listening for the $destroy event, like this:

```
var pull = $timeout($scope.loadPosts, 5000); // pull after 5 seconds

$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
  $timeout.cancel(pull);
});
```